# iOS - share key from keychain with service extension

Tags: ios, keychain

I need to share the private key that was generated by the main iOS app with the push notification service extension. Getting the key works fine within the app with SecItemCopyMatching(). But if I try to get the private key from within the service extension I get a "errSecItemNotFound".

Here is what I'm doing:

In the main app I generate a key pair and store it on the keychain with SecItemAdd(). I don't use the "kSecAttrIsPermanent: true" attribute while generating the key pair, because it doesn't allow to specify an "kSecAttrAccessGroup". As far as I understand the keychain sharing I need to specify an access group to share keys between apps, or between an extension and an app.

kSecAttrAccessGroup is a string that I specify which looks something like this: *"MyAppIdentifierPrefix" + "com.example.app.my-keychain"*
keyTag is also a string that i specify which looks something like this: *"com.example.app.my-key"*

```
    // private key parameters
    let privateKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyTag as AnyObject
    ]

    // public key parameters
    let publicKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyTag as AnyObject
    ]

    // global parameters for key generation
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as String:          myKeyType,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:    myKeySize as AnyObject,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:       publicKeyParams as AnyObject,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:      privateKeyParams as AnyObject
    ]

    // generate the key pair
    var pubKey, privKey: SecKey?
    let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &pubKey, &privKey)

    if status == errSecSuccess {
        // parameters for public key
        let pubKeyParameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,
            kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainGroupName as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyTag as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: myKeyType,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: myKeySize as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            kSecValueRef as String: pubKey!
        ]
        // add public key to keychain
        let statusPubKey = SecItemAdd(pubKeyParameters as CFDictionary, nil)

        // parameters for private key
        let privKeyParameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,
            kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainGroupName as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyTag as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: myKeyType,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: myKeySize as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
            kSecValueRef as String: privKey!
        ]
        // add private key to keychain
        let statusPrivKey = SecItemAdd(privKeyParameters as CFDictionary, nil)
    }
```

I enabled keychain sharing in the capabilities tab and specified the same identifier *"com.example.app.my-keychain"* for both the app and the push notification service extension.

My function to get the key bytes is as following:

```
func getPrivateKeyData(keyTag: String) -> Data? {
    let parameters = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyTag,
        kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainGroupName as AnyObject,
        kSecReturnData as String: true
        ] as [String : Any]
    var data: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(parameters as CFDictionary, &data)
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        return data as? Data
    } else { return nil }
}
```

This does not work so far...

Comment: have you enabled the Keychain sharing entitilement in your app and extensions "Capabilities" tabs (and defined your group ID)?

Comment: @CSmith Yes if have enabled keychain sharing in both the app and the extension. I defined the same keychain group for both and checked that it was written to the *.entitlements files. What do you mean by group ID?

Comment: group ID = the name of your shared keychain.  This is the "Keychain Access Groups" key in the entitlements.  It seems like you've got it setup right.  I'm not familiar with KeyClass or some of the other attributes, perhaps simplify your test case to just store a simple string (without some of these extra attributes) and see if you can share that amongst your app and extension.

Comment: @stsl Did you get any solution? If yes, then please share it over here.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode click on your main folder "App", then go to the tab "Signing & Capabilities", select your main project as the target on the left, then click the button "+ Capability" in the top left corner and add "Keychain Sharing". After that add your extension's bundle identifier to the Keychain Groups field. Then change the target to your extension and add Keychain Sharing the same way. Add your main app's bundle identifier in the keychain groups field.